# exception handling inside switch case

Tags: java, exception

i want java exception where the case not + , - , * or /  and on defualt i want to make exception show error like "Illegal arithmetic operation " on default

```
  private double evaluate(){
            double result ; 
           switch (operator) {
            case '-':
                result = left - right;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = left * right;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = left / right;
                break;
            case '+':
                result = left + right;
                break;
            default:   System.out.println ("ILLEGAL Arthemetic Operation " + operator);
             break;    //i want to show exception error here
        }
           return result;
           }
```

Comment: Why not just throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply throw the exception in `default` case

```
 default:   System.out.println ("ILLEGAL Arthemetic Operation " + operator);
            throw new Exception("Illegal Operation" + operator);
```

Comment: I think break is not required in default case

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder. No Not required. Just added it because it was in original question. I'll remove it.

Comment: One more thing It should also required the `throws Exception` statement with method signature

Answer (score 1):

You can just throw an exception - you can do that in that place in the code in the same way as any other:

```
// ....
default:   
    System.out.println ("ILLEGAL Arthemetic Operation " + operator);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("ILLEGAL Arthemetic Operation " + operator);
}
```

You don't need `break;` as it will never be reached.

Comment: I would create a new `Excetpion` class, or throw `IllegalArgumentException` for this case.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Yes, I saw your edit, makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follows

```
 private double evaluate(char operator) throws Exception{
        double result ; 
       switch (operator) {
        case '-':
            result = left - right;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = left * right;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = left / right;
            break;
        case '+':
            result = left + right;
            break;
        default:  
            throw new Exception("Illegal Operation" + operator);
          }
       return result;
       }
```